# Multi-tenancy in Chef

Tags: chef-infra, multi-tenant

I am new to Chef, I have read the documentation and watched some webinars. 
My understanding is that multi-tenancy is achieved using Chef Organizations. I also read that we cannot share cookbooks, roles, etc between different organizations.

What if each tenant will be using the same cookbooks, roles, etc? Supposing they might just need to use different versions of the same cookbooks. 
Is it secure to use a single organization and achieve multi-tenancy with environments? (I know environments are not intended for that, but rather for different stages of an organization workflow)

Also from what I read, a node running chef-client, can have its /etc/chef/client.rb edited and the environment changed, this would change the tenant for this node, using this approach.
Would it possible to prevent, on the chef-server side, the node from setting its own environment?

I guess this should be a common use case: having the exact same infrastructure, roles, etc for different tenants. How do you address this?

Thanks

Comment: It is usually addressed by organizations, cloning an org to another is quite easy, a workstation used to upload cookbooks can be configured to use one or the other org by the way of an environment variable for example (to choose the org and the validation key). I think you can't prevent a node from changing it's own env, but maybe the ACL system allow this kind of restriction.

Comment: @Tensibai I guess I could do that. I have my knife.rb using environment variables, I just need to automate the change of organization name and validator key location variables, and upload cookbooks, roles, etc. Or use Chef API to automate the organization synchronization